# Disable Multi Button Selection in iphone

Tags: iphone, mobile, sdk

I have 6 button for drop ball in my grid view. When I pressed button and at same time I pressed another button before release the first button.And release both button at a same time than my game is not working properly. So how to disable another button's click event when I have already hold one button??

The Game is like https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.co.aifactory.fialfree&hl=en see the screenshots there are 7 green down arrow button for dropping ball.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
    buttonName.enabled = NO;
```

When you call a function on a button click in that function disable all other buttons 
accordingly again enable them after you complete your task on the clicked button...I have not used this before but I think this will work for you..All the best..

Comment: but m not click on any button just hold that button and also same time click on another button..and release both button at same time..getting??

Comment: You are holding a button means you are tapping a button and not removing tap from button and in the same position you are tapping another button right?

Comment: Then on tap to a button you must have written a method which is getting called. In that method code disable other buttons so that when you will tap any other button it will not respond.